# Error when installing brew on macos big sur

Tags: macos

I install brew following

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

but not working

```
==> /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
mkdir: /usr/local/bin: Not a directory
Failed during: /usr/bin/sudo /bin/mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
```

Plzz help me. thanks

Comment: If there is a bug in the official installation process, please report it in Brew's issue tracker

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, general computer usage (installation, setup, etc); [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for this. But this sounds rather like [this problem](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/410418/why-usr-local-bin-is-showing-as-a-file-in-mac), where a file (not directory) got created under the name /usr/local/bin. Take a look, and if there's a file at that path, delete (or move or rename) it and try installing Homebrew again.